# A database table (MySQL) is still 20GiB after shrinking the text field by removing the unneeded html tags

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The table had a great large of data in one field (`TEXT` type). After some data was removed, the table is still the same size. A lot of data was removed that's why i'm sure that the table has to be much smaller (about 12GiB).

Maybe is there some cache or anything? How can i know the real size of the table?

I executed the query below in order to know the real size of the table, but it shows me the same size (20GiB) every time.

```sql
SELECT
    table_name AS `Table`,
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
    table_schema = "database name" AND table_name = "table name";
```

Comment: Rebuilding table/index: [ALTER TABLE Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html#rebuilding-tables-alter-table)?

Comment: @Katya , Please consider marking my answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @BlackBrain, You gave me a good advice but, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. When I tried to optimize the table, I always got an error.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to shrink the file size:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE "table-name";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easier way to resolve this problem.
I created a new table with the same columns and move data from my old table and after that, remove the old one. That's it.